# How to access remote machine to add/remove/manage users accounts?

Tags: c#, active-directory, impersonation, remote-access, principal

I have a scenario where I need to access a remote machine to programmatically add and delete Windows users accounts.
The remote machine is a "spare workstation" that I need to remotely configure, to be ready just in case the main workstation need to be replaced - so no security bypass or malicious software here :)

I know user/password of remote machine administrator, and I'm able to retrieve a complete list of existing users account using WMI Win32_UserAccount. Now, I'm trying to obtain an UserPrincipal object for each user (to eventually delete it), but I'm getting exceptions for all of my attempts.

- Attempt #1:

  ```
  PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" /*remote IP Address*/);
  UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "userName"));
  // Do something with user, like user.Delete();
  ```

  In this case I always get an exception in the first line:

  > System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException
  >   was caught   Message=The server could not be contacted.
  >   Source=System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement   StackTrace:
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String
  >   serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType
  >   contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options,
  >   String userName, String password)
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType
  >   contextType, String name, String container, String userName, String
  >   password)   InnerException:
  >   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException
  >          Message=The LDAP server is unavailable.
  >          Source=System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
  >          ErrorCode=81
  >          StackTrace:
  >               in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
  >               in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequestHelper(DirectoryRequest
  >   request, Int32& messageID)
  >               in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest
  >   request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
  >               in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest
  >   request)
  >               in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String
  >   serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
  >          InnerException:
- Attempt #2:

  ```
  PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" /*remote IP Address*/);
  UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "userName"));
  // Do something with user, like user.Delete();
  ```

  In this case I always get an exception in the second line:

  > System.IO.FileNotFoundException was caught   Message=Network path not
  >   found.
  >
  > Source=Active Directory   StackTrace:
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
  >   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
  >   identityValue, DateTime refDate)
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext
  >   context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
  >          in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
  >   context, String identityValue)
  >             InnerException:

I've tried different signatures of PrincipalContext object (with domain name instead of IP address, with user name and password, ...) but I always get exceptions on both attempts.

Am I missing some instructions? Do I need to use impersonation to gain full acces to remote machine before to create PrincipalContext object?
Any other ways to accomplish what I'am trying to do? (that is, access a remote machine to add/remove Windows account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the account, why not use Directory Services instead:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry deParent = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://[computername]", 
         @"[domain\adminname", "password");            
DirectoryEntry deToRemove = deParent.Children.Find("usernametoremove");
deParent.Children.Remove(deToRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't think about `DirectoryServices` to delete account. Do you know if with `DirectoryServices` class I will also be able to programmatically create new accounts and change users settings? Anyway, I will take a deep look at this class, thanks.

Comment: Certainly. The DirecoryEntry page in MSDN will show all the methods you need to do this. Don't forget to 'Commit' your changes! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx. Also, if this answered your question, please tick

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think this answers my question. I was so focused on `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, mainly because of the introduction of [the related MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , that I didn't think about the long-time existing `DirectoryEntry` class.

Answer (score -2):

If you are under domain, remove the IP address parameter and try using this.

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
  using(var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
  {
   //Do some stuff
  }
}
```

It's seems your Active directory could not be found using Ip Address

Comment: Hey, thanks! Using your sample code I don't get any exception, but both _pc_ and _up_ have all their properties set to _null_, so I can't do any operation with user object.  Other question: If I don't specify IP address, how can the code "understand" to which remote machine I'm referring?